# Can't return to any view after using Javascript/Ajax MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem that I don't have ideia how to resolve. I did an extensive research and can't find anything similar to this, even I don't have idea how to resolve or why it's occurring (probably because i'm new to mvc).

So, I have a **method**

```
public ActionResult EscolherFuncionarios()
        {
            SorteioEspecial sorteioEspecial = new SorteioEspecial();
            List<Funcionario> list = new List<Funcionario>();
            list = sorteioEspecial.GetFuncionarios().ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToList();
            ViewBag.FuncionarioId = new SelectList(list, "Id", "Nome");
            return View(sorteioEspecial);
        }
```

Who call this **view**

```
@model ApdlSorteio.Models.SorteioEspecial

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    <div class="col-md-10" style="float:left">
        @Html.DropDownList("FuncionarioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "chosen-select", @data_placeholder = "Escolha os funcionários para sorteio", @multiple = "true" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
        <div class="col-md-10" style="float:left">
            <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" class="btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <br />
    <br />

    <div id="MyDiv"></div>
    <div class="form-group" style="float:left">
        <div class="col-md-10" style="float:left">
            <input type="submit" value="Editar ponderações" class="breadcrumb" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />




<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.proto.js"></script>
<link href="~/Scripts/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/chosen.jquery.js"></script>



<script>
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
        disable_search_threshold: 10,
        no_results_text: "Nenhum funcionário encontrado!",
        width: "95%"
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".breadcrumb").on("click", function (event, params) {
        var selectedValues = [];
        $(".chosen-select :selected").each(function () {
            selectedValues.push($(this).attr('value'));
        }); 
        $.post('@Url.Action("EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond","Sorteios")', { bdoIds: selectedValues });

        });
    });
</script>
```

In the script, I have a button that will call the method **EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond**, wich have this code

```
public ActionResult EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond(string[] bdoIds)
        {
            List<PonderacaoFuncionario> Getpf = new List<PonderacaoFuncionario>();
            Getpf = service.GetPonderacaoFuncionario().ToList();

            List<PonderacaoFuncionario> pfList = new List<PonderacaoFuncionario>();

            for (int x = 0; x < bdoIds.Count(); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Getpf.Count(); y++)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(bdoIds[x]) == Getpf[y].Funcionario)
                    {
                        pfList.Add(Getpf[y]);
                    }
                }
            }

            //return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = 90 });
            return View(pfList);
        }
```

that will call this **view**

```
@model IEnumerable<ApdlModel.Entities.PonderacaoFuncionario>

<div class="filterbox">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Funcionario)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome_Funcionario)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ponderacao)</b>
            </th>
            <th>
                <b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Incluir_sorteio)</b>
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Funcionario)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Funcionario)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ponderacao)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Incluir_sorteio)
                </td>
            }
        </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

The problem is that the view doesnt show. At the beggining I was thinking that it will be a problem on view, so I used a RedirectToAction (like you can see commented on controller), but this doesnt show any view also, but If I go to the method "Details" by another page its working. I really dont now whats going on, need some help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `$.post` it calls your action then gets back a bunch of HTML.  And then you do nothing with it, so the browser just throws it away.  If you want to just go to the new page, do a regular post and don't use ajax.  Ajax is more for if you need to call your server to get some information to UPDATE the current page, not go to a new one.

**EDIT**

To do a regular post, wrap everything in a form, set the action to post and put the submit button somewhere in there.  Also, drop the javascript post stuff.  To create the form, look into using [Html.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you tell me how I do a _regular post_?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the View() method without specifying the name of the view, your code will be searching a view of the same name as the method inside of the folder that you have configured your routes for in AreaRegistration.

Make sure that your view is in the correct folder, and also that it has an identical name to the method that calls it if you are going to call the View() method with no string name.

If you say calling "Details" works, put your desired view in the same folder (if it isn't) as the details view, or change your routes' configuration to match the view.

Comment: I've checked that before posting. Had did tests with anothers views too. Only this (that used the javascript) isn't capable of calling a view

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the return value of the AJAX call. Unlike loading a URL traditionally via the address bar, when you make an AJAX call, the browser will not do anything on its own. You are responsible for doing something with the response. In this case, adding the returned HTML to the DOM. This is done via the callback.

```
$.post('@Url.Action("EditarPonderacoesEspecialSecond","Sorteios")', { bdoIds: selectedValues }, function (result) {
    $('#SomeElement').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying Viewpath in 
" return View(obj)"

like

"return View(@"~\Views\Shared\Home",obj)"